# uniqueness with multiple keys in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I want to have any field unique and avoid duplications I use the syntax described as follows

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  projectName : String,
  authorName : { type: String, index: true }
});
```

But what if I want to have the value of pairs of (projectName, authorName) unique. I know that mongodb supports this with

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { a: 1, b: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

How do I write the same thing in mongoose? What is the syntax for doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a schema level index, as in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes):

```
schema.index({projectName:1, authorName:1}, { unique: true });
```